# Why isn't 2008 server R2 x64 accepting cookies

Tags: windows, wininet

I have http connection code that does the typical
 InternetOpen -> InternetConnect -> HttpOpenRequest -> HttpSendRequest using wininet, 
which worked just fine on all the prior versions of windows , but win server r2 x64 what is happening is that everything else works just fine  but the cookies aren't being accepted and returned on subsequent calls( I love wireshark) ( causing things to fail).  So I've been starting at the various flags and options available to the 4 different calls, as well as InternetSetOption and InternetSetPerSiteCookieDecision.  And I just haven't seemed to find a way to make 2008 server accept the cookies yet.  The only catch is that I'm using a straight ip (say 192.0.0.1(not real ip) )and not something like www.foo.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918417.aspx

please check: "Privacy settings" and "Per site cookie handling"

Comment: nice!  I also figured out that part of the issue is that unfortunatley wininet settings and internet explorer settings are somewhat unseparateable.. which means you can't temporarily over ride "Block All Cookies" ( without querying/ restoring settings) for just the session. So What I'm forced to do is use PrivacySetZonePreference to change the preference from block all to high ( and add the site I want as an allowed site). (however to add fun I happen to be running as local system which is where your link to check the registry settings comes in *real* handy.